# Filling listbox using dat file

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, listbox, binaryfiles

There is code present in application which fills list box from binary dat files which get data from  table in database.
Code being used is

```
 public string getclientid(string sectorid)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dsobj = new DataSet();
            bllobj = new ConverterClass();
            string retclientval = "0";

            dsobj = bllobj.BinaryDeSerialize(strDataPath + "\\" + "BinaryClientlocation.dat");
            DataRow[] dr = dsobj.Tables[0].Select("client_location_id in(" + locationid + ")");
            if (dr.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow drow in dr)
                {
                    retclientval = retclientval + "," + drow["client_id"].ToString();
                }
            }
            return retclientval;
        }
```

How to find which is the table from which the binary file is generated so that I can add new client .
DBMS used is Sql Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the database the .dat file comes from, then you probably don't need a binary file to populate a list box. Look into datasets, or `Linq to SQL`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way this code is going to help you.
Once you have read data from db and written it out in your own binary format, it has no relation to a database table.

You should go looking for the code that writes the `BinaryClientlocation.dat` file.